# Matlab ksdensity not working properly

Tags: matlab

I am working with a strictly positive observation vector (they are a distance measure).
I use `ksdensity` with this vector to get a feeling of the density function and surprisingly it includes negative values. Meaning that there is a positive probability to observe an all negative values interval.
This is not correct because I know my observations are all positives.

Why is `ksdensity` doing this? I have the feeling that it completes the curve assuming continuous differentiability. Is this a correct assumption?

Is there any option where Matlab doesn't guess and just gives a "Derivate" of the empirical cumulative function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability density estimate that [`ksdensity`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) returns is based off the assumption of a normal kernal function. If your data has values near zero, you'll naturally get some overlap into the negative as the individual kernels are summed:

[image]

([Image Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation))

A histogram won't have this problem since it only displays values that actually exist. To remedy the error, you can specify a different distribution (termed by Mathworks as the 'kernel smoother'), or even add a custom one. For example:

`[f,xi] = ksdensity(x,pts,'kernel','epanechnikov')`

replaces the normal distribution with an epanechnikov.

**Edit:**

...and proving that you should always read the documentation first, I just discovered that you can limit your kernel density estimation to positive values only:

```
x = gamrnd(5,7,1000,1);
[f,xi] = ksdensity(x,'support','positive');
figure
plot(xi,f,'linewidth',2)
```

Comment: Thanks. But then.. is there any matlab function that "derivates" de empirical CDF? I really don't like histograms

Comment: I'd look into how to plug in a chi-squared or gamma distribution if I were you. I'm not sure how to pass two parameters though. Maybe open up the ksdensity file and see how it uses the normal distribution, then adapt it.