# How ksdensity calculates each data point xi?

Tags: matlab, statistics, kernel-density

When I use `[f,xi] = ksdensity(x)` in Matlab, I get the probability density estimate, *f*, and *xi* evaluation points at which ksdensity calculates *f*.

My question is: How is each *xi* point calculated/determined? Is there a formula?

The documentation center says: *Default is 100 equally spaced points that cover the range of data in x*. So, they cover the range, but this does not explain how are calculated.

Thank you very much!

Juan

Comment: I suppose `xi(i)=min(x)+i*(max(x)-min(x))/100`

Answer (score 0):

The standard method of achieving equally spaced points in MATLAB is using the `linspace` command. `linspace(a,b,n)` generates `n` linearly spaced points between and including `a` and `b`.

So it most probably is equivalent to `xi = linspace(min(x),max(x))` (default number of points is 100 in`linspace`).

Comment: Thank you very much @pseudoDust and ramanan, but none of your answers seems to work. 
If I use as an example: 
`Data=[365629;258213;30986;340841;82628;92957;10329;454454;0;51643;309855;82628;51643;10329;41314;41314;330512;0;92957;227227;123942;433797;423469;464783;826280;433797;206570;433797;61971;123942;82628;0;113614;960551;557739;113614;113614];

[PDF,xi]=ksdensity(Data,'kernel','epanechnikov','npoints',10);

xi_ramanan= linspace(min(Data),max(Data),10);

for i=1:100;
    xi_pseudoDust(i)=min(Data)+i*(max(Data)-min(Data))/100;
end;`

The results are not the same as ksdensity's _xi_ =/

Comment: Ok. It is clearer now that you have shown your data. The anomaly is because of the presence of 0s. Due to them, there will be some overlap of your data with negative values, resulting in `xi` which were not original present in `Data`. A more detailed explanation is provided at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410155/matlab-ksdensity-not-working-properly

Comment: Thanks! I've had read that thread before, but my question remain the same: How is each _xi_ calculated? =P